# gcc compiling error on Solaris 10

Tags: gcc, solaris, solaris-10, compare-and-swap

I want to compile a source code, but there are some compiling errors about `__sync_xxx` functions (`__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` etc.)

GCC version on machine is 3.4.3 (it must be gcc 4.1 or over for supporting atomic builtins), so I have downloaded GCC v4.6, copied it to another directory (I didn't remove v3.4.3) then change the `$PATH` path for GCC but it doesn't work (the same error occurs).

I want to ask that is only changing gcc path with `export PATH=...` enough for compiling with new GCC?

Comment: In the context of your build environment type `gcc --version` to see if it is finding the correct toolchain.

Comment: did you run whatever configure step is appropriate for that build?

Comment: Could you please show the full output, passing '-v' to enable more details?

Comment: bash-3.00# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/akala/GCC/install/libexec/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.6.0/lto-wrapper
Target: i386-pc-solaris2.10
Configured with: ../gcc-4.6.0/configure --prefix=/opt/akala/GCC/install --with-gmp=/opt/akala/GCC/libs/install --with-mpfr=/opt/akala/GCC/libs/install --with-mpc=/opt/akala/GCC/libs/install --with-gettext=/opt/akala/GCC/libs/install --disable-checking --enable-werror --enable-languages=c
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.6.0 (GCC)

Comment: @dldnh
sorry i couldnt understand which configure u mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following **configure** option when compiling gcc:

```
--program-prefix=foo --program-suffix=bar
```

and it will produce bin programs of the form "foo-gcc-bar", so that you may differentiate different builds of gcc.

Replace foo and/or bar with an appropriate "tag" for your build (eg "-4.6" for example).

This way if it doesn't find your toolchain correctly it will fail fast rather than using the 3.4 version.

It also means that different toolchain builds can coexist in the standard installation prefix directories.

Answer (score 0):

We have to use -march=686 switch to get it to work on intel.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking and updating `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, to use the lib path for the new gcc installed.